Custom 404 page making Images, CSS and Javascript fail with 500
I have a custom [Page Not Found] page. This is triggered by the below custom processor.
<httpRequestBegin>
 ... 
  <processor type="namespace.proj.Pipelines.PageNotFoundProcessor, namespace.proj" patch:source="Pipeline.PageNotFound.config"/>

So far so good. The [Page Not Found] is coming up fine when the requested page doesn't exists. But when i see the Status code, i am getting 200. I need to change that to 404 and hence added one more processor. Called it under  as shown below.
<httpRequestProcessed>
  ..
  <processor type="namespace.proj.Pipelines.SetResponseStatusProcessor, namespace.proj" patch:source="Pipeline.PageNotFound.config"/>

..also the processor code is as below.
public class SetResponseStatusProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (Context.Item.Name == "Page Not Found")
        {
            args.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            args.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}

with this the page status code is returned correctly as 404 (screenshot below)

But a new problem emerged like all Images, CSS and Javascripts are not loaded and throwing 500 error as shown below.

Any ideas/ suggestions what might be wrong?

Is there any error on the log files? If possible can you also share the code for pagenotfound processor..

@ckhanna, Thanks for looking. I have taken more closer look and it seems that there is an NRE exception which is not handled. Once i handled that the exceptions went away.

The problem is due to an NRE exception and the condition below is changed from
if (Context.Item.Name == "Page Not Found") -->if (Context.Item?.Name == "Page Not Found")

